# Как заставить див не перескакивать вниз при увеличении масштаба?

Tags: html, css

Привет.

Есть два дива (или три) и идея была такова: есть главный див, в нем находится два дива, большой и маленький (правый). И они должны находится всегда рядом горизонтально.

При увеличении в браузере "ctrl" + "+" (или еще такое возможно, когда пользователь установил свои шрифты), боковая колонка (правая) съезжает вниз.

Как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило, без использования таблиц? Это возможно?

Примерный код:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="big">700px</div>
<div class="small">250px Этот див улетает вниз в некоторых случаях. </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main{
    padding-left:135px;
    min-height: 700px;
}

.big{
    height: 100%;
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
}

.small{
    height: 100%;
    margin-left:50px;
    width: 250px;
    float:left;/*<-----это наверное ошибка?*/
    clear: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо у родительского дива установить

```
min-width:1024px; /*В некоторых ИЕ глючит*/
```

Либо в самый верх родительского дива вставить див со следующими параметрами:

```
width: 1024px;
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
```

У body следует вставить

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Comment: спасибо большое! это, то что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

А если попробовать указывать размеры не в пикселях, а в процентах? Может прокатит...

Comment: с просто width --не прокатило.
с min-width -- тоже не прокатило.

думаю дело в том, что к 100% прибавляется значение паддинга.
щас попробую с марджином....

Comment: с марджином(правильно говорю?) та же история.

Comment: Должно было прокатить. Значит либо у вас какое-то из этих свойств перекрывается чем-то еще, либо вы что-то не так чделали.